# Definition of output of Quanteda findSequence function - R package for text analysis

Tags: r, quanteda

quick question:

The R text analysis package Quanteda - findSequence gives the following output and I can't find documentation on some of the columns:

```
seqs <- findSequences(tokens, types_upper, count_min=2)
head(seqs, 3)
              sequence len          z         p       mue
     3         first time   2 -0.4159751 0.6612859 -165.7366
     8  political parties   2 -0.4159751 0.6612859 -165.7366
     9   preserve protect   2 -0.4159751 0.6612859 -165.7366
```

Can someone help with definitions of z, p and mue
is p = probability? and if so, how calculated. The help says, "This algorithm is based on Blaheta and Johnson's “Unsupervised Learning of Multi-Word Verbs”." but provides no further detail of output components.

Looks like and interesting function but more information would help.

Comment: This is a good question but it may not be the best here. I would suggest migrating to Cross Validated. They may send it back but someone familiar with the process may help.

Comment: Judging by the function details, it looks like `z` is a z-score, `p` is the probability of getting that score, and `mue` is the mean. But maybe someone else can check it.

Comment: thanks Pierre - appreciated!

Comment: Note: This was an experimental function, and in v0.9.9 was renamed to `sequences`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the function code and then checking the paper, `z` is calculated from lambda (log-odds ratio) over sigma (asymptotic standard error). It's a z-score, like Pierre commented, and `p` is a probability `1 - stats::pnorm(z)`.

`mue` is explained in the second paragraph in section 2.3 of Blaheta and Johnson's "Unsupervised Learning of Multi-Word Verbs." "µ = λ − 3.29σ.... This corresponds to setting the measures µ and µ1 to the lower bound of a 0.001 confidence interval for λ..., which is a systematic way of trading recall for precision in the face of noisy data (Johnson, 2001)."

If you go to section 2.3, you can see further details:

> We propose two different measures of association µ and µ1, which we
>   call the “all subtuples” and “unigram subtuples” measures below. As we
>   explain below, they seem to identify very different kinds of
>   collocations, so both are useful in certain circumstances. These
>   measures are estimates of λ and λ1 respectively, which are particular
>   parameters of certain log-linear models. In cases where the counts are
>   small the estimates of λ and λ1 may be noisy, and so high values from
>   small count data should be discounted in some way when being compared
>   with values from large count data. We do this by also estimating the
>   asymptotic standard error σ and σ1 of λ and λ1 respectively, and set µ
>   = λ − 3.29σ and µ1 = λ1 − 3.29σ1. This corresponds to setting the measures µ and µ1 to the lower bound of a 0.001 confidence interval
>   for λ and λ1 respectively, which is a systematic way of trading recall
>   for precision in the face of noisy data (Johnson, 2001).

The details (and additional references) pertaining to calculating λ and σ are also in section 2.3